# How to add header above the Tabnav

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

Like this one..

This tab navigator is in inside of the stack navigator. I have added my code below. I just want to add header like above image above this TabNavigator.

```
const tabnavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{
      screen:HomeStack,
      navigationOptions:{
        //tabBarLabel:'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor,focused}) =>(

             <Image style={{width:18,height:20}} source={image = focused? require('../images/Icons/HomeIcons/homered3x.png') : require('../images/Icons/HomeIcons/home3x.png')}/>

        ),
      }
  },
  Packages:{
      screen:PackagesStack,
      navigationOptions:{
        //tabBarLabel:'Packages',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor,focused})=>(

            <Image style={{width:15,height:20}} source={image = focused? require('../images/Icons/HomeIcons/packagesred3x.png') : require('../images/Icons/HomeIcons/packages3x.png')}/>

        )


      }

  }
},{tabBarOptions:{showLabel:false,showIcon:true,tabStyle:{backgroundColor:'white'}}});

const tabnav = createAppContainer(tabnavigator);


export default tabnav;
```

[image]

Comment: Would be great if you could show us the code rather than making us assume the situation

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have added my sample code.

Comment: Can you show the image of your current output , I want to see where the Home is positioned in your output

Comment: image added....

Comment: Have you tried **navigationOptions** in Home?

Comment: @miladsolgi actually I want to add that header for every tabs.. not only for one view. Thanks for ur response.